# I am trying to make as simple hello world passing JS data into server side python

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have tried using several online resources, but I figured I would ask here if anyone is willing to help. I am making a website with a very little front end (js/html/css) with data that is then processed on the server side with python. I am a relatively experienced python programmer but am quite new at JavaScript.

I would appreciate if someone could direct me to a resource or show how I can pass javascript data (like which button is clicked) to a python script. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you start looking into AJAX. Here is a [resource](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/jquery/) on the flask site itself which is still pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

in javascript, you'd so something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8889/mainApp?color=red&size=11',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result){console.log(result)},
    error: function(error){alert(error)}
});
```

for python, I'd recommend [tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/). I modified its hello-world example a little:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import json

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        color = self.get_argument('color')
        size = int(self.get_argument('size'))
        result = {}
        result['font_color'] = color # do your calculation/processing with data
        result['font_size'] = size # do your calculation/processing with data
        self.write(json.dumps(result)) 

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/mainApp", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8889)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

notice the matching symbols in code: `"8889"` (the port), `"/mainApp"` (the url), `"MainHandler"` (what writes back to your ajax GET request)

Answer (score 0):

Need more advance or straight forward solution you can always try to explore something new like react, hope this reference could help you [flask and react](https://realpython.com/the-ultimate-flask-front-end/)